# How to extract to single cell value in multiple columns in csv through powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Please find attached link of CSV FILE:
https://www.filemail.com/d/bhbzeopkibjnvpq

[image]I have below Value in A1 cell:

```
A;"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G"
```

I want to split to next column header like as below:

```
A B C D E F G
```

Note: A B C D E F G this is individual column header.

I'm using below powershell command but no luck:

```
$CSVpath = "D:\test.csv"
$data = import-csv $CSVpath
$b=$data[0].psobject.properties.name
$b = $b -split ';'
write-host $b 
$csvRows | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 $CSVpath
```

P.S. I wanna make dynamic script instead of static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stick with plain-text processing (note that the raw header row from the linked CSV file is `"A;""B"";""C"";""D"";""E"";""F"";""G""",,,,`):

```
$CSVpath = "D:\test.csv"

# Read the whole file into the header row and all data rows.
$header, $data = Get-Content $CSVpath

# Repair the header:
#  * Remove all double quotes and commas,
#  * then replace the semicolons with commas, which yields:
#    A,B,C,D,E,F,G
$repairedHeader = $header -replace '[",]' -replace ';', ','

# Save the repaired header and all data rows back to the file.
# Adjust -Encoding as needed.
Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $CSVPath -Value $repairedHeader, $data
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not read the first line to extract the header then apply to the remaining lines:

```
$CSVpath = "C:\temp\test.csv"
$Data    = Get-Content $CSVpath
$Headers = $Data[0] -Split ';'
$Headers = $Headers -replace '\"|,'

$Data |
Select-Object -Skip 1 |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Headers |
Export-Csv -Path $CSVpath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
```

There's some funky quoting in the source data. So, I replaced the quotes as well as the trailing commas.  However, this should result in proper field mapping to that first line.