# How to split single column (Have multiple value) into multi value through powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have CSV File , that contains with multiple value in single column , I wanna split every value to next columns. Please find below attached Image[image]

I am using below code but no any luck around:

```
$CSVpath1 = "G:\Test.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $CSVpath1 -Delimiter ';'
$p= (Get-Member -InputObject $csv[0] -MemberType Properties).Name
foreach ($property in $p) {
    $csv | Select-Object @{n=$p;e={$_.$p}} |
        Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$p.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
}
```

Please find attached CSV file : [Test CSV](https://www.filemail.com/d/momvdpfntiamium)

Comment: Haven't you ask this question already yesterday or a few days ago?

Comment: @Olaf I think it's slightly different.

Comment: @Steven ... hmmm ... some could argue about this.  ;-)  ... but since you've already answered ...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `$p`?  Embedded in a `ForEach-Object` loop, the most I can suspect is you'll end up with a file per property.  I very much doubt that's the intent.

Comment: Try something like this `(Get-Content $CSVpath1) -replace '(?<!")"([^"]+?)(?=[;,])', '""$1""' -replace '"{2,}', '"' -replace ",{2,}", ';;' -replace ';', ','  | Set-Content .\output.csv`

Comment: @Olaf possible I'm thrown by the different headers, delimiters etc...  Hope it's not homework, LOL.

Comment: It was asked last night and looks to be deleted now.

Comment: @Daniel The one I referenced in the answer is still there, if you want to have a look.  Your approach might be relevant there too, if you want to post it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69057409/4749264). Similar techniques of mixing string manipulation with the native Csv cmdlets.

```
$CSVpath = "c:\temp\test1.csv"
$Data    = Get-Content $CSVpath
$Headers = $Data[0] -split ','

$Data = ($Data | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '\"|,'    
    
$Data | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Headers -Delimiter ";"
```

Bring in the file, use the first line to determine the headers. Then convert the remaining lines from CSV to PSObjects using the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet with the `-Headers` & `-Delimiter` params.  Also replacing what looks like superfluous quoting.

That will result in objects that look like:

```
H1 h2 H3 H4  H5 H6 H7                 H8 H9 H10
-- -- -- --  -- -- --                 -- -- ---
A  B  C  D   E  F  G,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
H  I  J  K   L  M  N                  O  P  Q
A  B  C  D   E  F  G,,,,,,,,H         I  J  K
10 a  C  D,H I  J  K                  L  M  N
```

However, it's unclear what's to be done with the commas.  I would suggest the data be cleaned up beforehand.

Replacing the commas as in the previous answer and also overwriting the original file:

```
$CSVpath = "c:\temp\test1.csv"
$Data    = Get-Content $CSVpath
$Headers = $Data[0] -split ','

$Data = ($Data | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '\"|,'

$Data | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Headers -Delimiter ";" | 
Export-Csv -Path $CSVpath -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Withstanding the export this should look like:

```
H1 h2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- ---
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q
A  B  C  D  E  F  GH I  J  K
10 a  C  DH I  J  K  L  M  N
```

Note: Both tables were output using `Format-Table` which by default truncates some of the columns.  Use `Format-Table * -AutoSize` to see the full table.

All can be shortened down to:

```
$CSVpath = "c:\temp\test1.csv"
$Data    = Get-Content $CSVpath
$Headers = $Data[0] -Split ','

($Data | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '\"|,' |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Headers -Delimiter ";" | 
Export-Csv -Path $CSVpath -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation

# To trim superfluous ";" belonging to emty fields.
(Get-Content $CSVpath).TrimEnd(';') | Set-Content $CSVpath
```

Note: For a true Csv file it's unnecessary to remove trailing `;`.  They are natural representations of properties that don't have a value. At any rate, and per request, I added some code to remove them.

Comment: Steven, Thanks for Answering my question , Appreciate.
I have run last script but still result is not in getting as you mention ,I got below result:
H1;"h2";"H3";"H4";"H5";"H6";"H7";"H8";"H9";"H10";"H11";"H12";"H13";"H14";"H15";"H16";"H17";"H18"
A;"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";;;;;;;;;;;

Is there any missing in last code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code.  The extra `;` in the file is because there are empty fields in the original data. The first data line of the file has 7 pieces of data, but there are 18 fields defined by the header.  hence when it's exported the emty property values look that way. Note: Output to table truncates columns. As a test you can force it to display everything like: `Import-Csv "C:\temp\test1.csv" -Delimiter ";" | Format-Table *`

Comment: is there any solution for that?

Comment: While I don't think it's necessary for a true Csv file, I added some code to clean those out.  Assume it's working, please consider accepting the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nilam I think I've addressed everything within the scope of the question.  If you are comfortable can you accept the answer, it helps other people find it and learn from it.

Comment: Thanks again Steven , For your Help!!